# css ::after and ::before selectors go to the next line - how to prevent

Tags: css, pseudo-element

I have been trying to add an image next to my navigation menu using CSS pseudo selectors ::before or ::after.

```
.menu_container::before{
    content: "";
    background: transparent url('ISO.png') no-repeat;
    position:relative;
    float:right;
    width: 50px;
    height:100px;
}
```

When i use above code, the image is positioned on a line before the actual menu. When I use the ::after selector it goes to the next line.

I have tried almost all the solutions given in this forum for similar issues. But nothing worked. Really appreciate your support.

Thanks heaps.

Comment: Need to see your HTML.

Comment: add this **display: inline** or **display: inline-block**;

Comment: Please create a fiddle showcasing your code & issues.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.....

```
.menu_container{
     position: relative;
 }

.menu_container::before{
     position: absolute;
}
```

/* now u can change where ever you want your before , after div */

Answer (score 0):

You would need to place the `:before` pseudo element in a way that it will always be positioned according to where the 'actual' element is.

So, to achieve this, you will need to first ensure your 'main' element is positioned `relative`ly:

```
.menu_container{
    position:relative;
    display:inline-block; /*more than likely needed for elements*/
}
```

That's realistically the only **required** CSS you need on the parent for this to work.

For your pseudo element, you shouldn't look to use a `float` as that will take the pseudo out of the flow of the dom - we don't want that. We can to position it according to the next relatively positioned parent (which we have just made as the main element).

```
.menu_container:before{
    content: "";
    background: transparent url('ISO.png') no-repeat;
    position:absolute;
    top: 0;
    left:0;
    height:100%;
    width:50px;
}
```

I would also suggest removing the double `::` and replacing with a single `:` for better browser support (old IE doesn't like the double colon syntax).

So the `Position:absolute` will allow you to use the `top:`, `left:`, `bottom:` and/or `right:` properties to position it according to this relative parent.